# Best method for manipulating the elements of a remote source modal in Bootstrap 3.1+?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, custom-data-attribute, bootstrap-modal

Is listening for the modal `shown.bs.modal` event, and using custom data attributes on the clicked element, the best way to manipulate the elements of a remote source modal in Bootstrap 3.1+?

I can't use the `show.bs.modal` or `loaded.bs.modal` events because the remote source modal elements are not loaded into the DOM when those events trigger.

http://jsfiddle.net/dbasch/UbpS6/

---

*main.html*

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="/remote.html" data-target="#myModal" data-merchant-name="Bob's House of Pancakes">Click me !</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="te"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->

<script type="text/javascript">

// we can't use the show.bs.modal or loaded.bs.modal events
// because the remote modal elements are not accessible in the DOM
// when those events trigger

// when the remote modal content is loaded  
// $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.loaded', function (e) {

    // get a data attribute value from the clicked element
    // var merchantName = $(e.relatedTarget).data('merchant-name');

    // and set the content of the shown remote modal
    // $('#myModalLabel').text("shown.bs.loaded event triggered");
//
// });

// when the remote modal content is shown  
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {

    // get a data attribute value from the clicked element
    var merchantName = $(e.relatedTarget).data('merchant-name');

    // and set the content of the shown remote modal
    $('#myModalLabel').text(merchantName);

});

// cleanup the content of the hidden remote modal because it is cached
$('#reservationModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {

    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');

});

</script>
```

---

*remote.html*

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>

        </button>
         <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- start slipsum code -->
        <p>The path of the righteous man is beset on all sides by the iniquities of the selfish and the tyranny of evil men. Blessed is he who, in the name of charity and good will, shepherds the weak through the valley of darkness, for he is truly his brother's keeper and the finder of lost children. And I will strike down upon thee with great vengeance and furious anger those who would attempt to poison and destroy My brothers. And you will know My name is the Lord when I lay My vengeance upon thee.</p>
        <!-- please do not remove this line -->
        <div style="display:none;">
<a href="http://slipsum.com">lorem ipsum</a>
        </div>
        <!-- end slipsum code -->
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looking at the BS source code and the jQuery docs, the `loaded.bs.modal` event should fire after the remote HTML has been inserted into the DOM, so it ought to work...

Comment: [The `remote` option is (being) deprecated](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/14034) anyway though, so you might as well avoid it and instead do the loading yourself.

Comment: Agreed @cvrebert, but it does not work as expected. I have updated the code and jsfiddle to show such.

Comment: Arghhh @cvrebert regarding `remote` being deprecated! There goes 10 hours of fiddling :(.

Comment: @cvrebert where can I find some examples of using client side templating with modals instead?

Comment: Don't know of any off the top of my head. You basically (0) Setup your own click handler on the modal trigger button (1) In the handler, load the remote (typically JSON) data (using jQuery.ajax or whatever) (2) In the AJAX callback, shove the data into your ViewModel or template vars, and render into HTML (3) Call `.modal('show')`. There are many library options, e.g. Hogan.js, Knockout.js, AngularJS, etc. Don't forget to handle the error if the AJAX request fails!

Comment: Thanks @cvrebert! It looks like I am relying on server side templating (sailjs w/ EJS) too much and it is time to transition to client side templating.